# TTreeview limit the node editing text length

Tags: c++builder

I am using TTreeView in C++ Builder XE7. I am allowing users to edit the node text on certain nodes, but I need to limit the amount of characters they can type in to 10.

How, and when, should I get the edit control and set it text limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`OnEditing`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.OnEditing) event, you can send a [`TVM_GETEDITCONTROL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773576.aspx) message to the TreeView to get the `HWND` of its edit field, then you can send a [`EM_LIMITTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761607.aspx) message to it.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::TreeView1Editing(TObject* Sender, TTreeNode* Node, bool &AllowEdit)
{
    AllowEdit = ...;
    if (AllowEdit)
    {
        HWND hEdit = TreeView_GetEditControl(TreeView1->Handle);
        SendMessage(hEdit, EM_LIMITTEXT, 10, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking into the ttreeview control itself for this info. Never even thought of looking directly into Win32 or macros.  Thanks!

Comment: The VCL wraps a lot of things, but it does not wrap everything. It is not uncommon for many non-trivial VCL apps to dip into the Win32 API directly.